MediaElement 4.1.0 NET MAUI Windows Problem Source Binding
Does anyone know how to set Resource. Specifically MediaSource.FromResource on Windows MAUI 8 from C#?
I have XAML:
<tools:MediaElement x:Name="MusicVip"
    IsVisible="False" Source="{Binding Mediasource}"
/>

C# code:
[ObservableProperty]
private MediaSource mediasource =
MediaSource.FromResource("HTML/Music/NameMusicFile.mp3");

If I try to change the path from / to .
It will no longer throw the error but Media will still not find the file.
[ObservableProperty]
private MediaSource mediasource =
MediaSource.FromResource("HTML.Music.NameMusicFile.mp3");

NameMusicFile.mp3 I have set Build Action to MauiAsset
My HTML folder is in the Root Project Folder (In SharedProject). The full path as I see it in VisualStudio is:
NameSolution/NameProject/HTML

And strangely, when I run the loop below to list all the names in MauiAsset, everything related to MauiAsset is empty, but Embeded resource is logged on Debug Console..
public void ListAllResources()
{
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    var resourceNames = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
    foreach (var resourceName in resourceNames)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(resourceName);
    }
}

I'm using:
Microsoft.Maui.Controls 8.0.82
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility 8.0.82
Microsoft.Maui.Essentials 8.0.82
ComunityToolkit.Maui 9.0.3
ComunityToolkit.Mvvm 8.3.0

And some other libraries that are not convenient to list...
The above code always runs on both platforms with MediaElement version 4.0.1. Android 34 and Windows 11 SDK 10.0.22621.0, but it always fails when I run on Windows 11 SDK 10.0.26100.0
Exception thrown: 'System.UriFormatException'

Since version 4.1.0 is quite new, I have consulted the official documentation at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/mediaelement?tabs=windows
But the documentation only explains some basic things and has no sample code. Since the version is quite new, I can't find any other documentation at all.
A temporary workaround is to install and use the old version: MediaElelement 4.0.1 but this will not bring any new things on version 4.1.0

For this problem, you can create a new issue here.

I played with the media element in recent days, and struggled to get binding to a Media source working. In the end, I created a state object for the player, and the bound to the file path as a string.

Yes, but, my problem is still there. i still use old version MediaElement 4.0.1

Hi @HưngNguyễn, have you posted a new issue? And could you please share the issue's link here?
